# How can I change the status code of the page in Next.js 13?

Tags: reactjs, next.js13

I want to change the status code in a NextJs 13 project, depeding on my api response. And i cant find a way to do it.

I am using the app directory, so i cannot use getserversideprops.

This is my page.tsx file inside the app directory

```
import { getData } from '../../lib/getData';

type PageProps = { params: { segments: Array<string> | undefined } };

export default async function Page({ params }: PageProps) {
  const data = await getData(params.segments);

  return <MyComponent context={data} />;
}
```

and here is my getdata()

```
import type { PageData } from '../types/cms';

export async function getData(pathSegments: Array<string> = []): Promise<PageData | undefined> {
  const apiEndpoint = `${process.env.API_URL}${pathSegments.length > 0 ? `/${pathSegments.join('/')}/` : ''}`;
  const res = await fetch(apiEndpoint, { redirect: 'follow', cache: 'no-store' });

  const jsonResponse = await res.json();

  return jsonResponse;
}
```

My api delivers status codes, and I want to change the status code of the page and use the status codes I get from my model.

[when i inspect the page I wish the status code to be my own](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPxcw.png)

Comment: I have the same issue, have you ever found a solution?

Comment: I used a middleware to handle redirects returning NextResponse.redirect(RedirectUrl, 301).

In the middleware I set a new header:

const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers);
requestHeaders.set('request-pathname', request.nextUrl.pathname);

const response = NextResponse.next({
    request: {
      headers: requestHeaders,
    },
  });

And for 404, I am returning the notFound() page from next13, and there I use the headers to get the data from the api.

Comment: U can use the getData function multiple times in ur application. That wont cost another refetch. Thats been said in the documentation. So I can use this function in the notFound page (which doesnt accept any props but returns 404 by default), to get the data i need to print in the 404 page